# Timer on Opening Workbook - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I created a macro that automatically opens a "raw" workbook file, does some calculations/manipulations, then saves it in another location. However, sometimes the original "raw" data file has corrupted characters that causes excel to get stuck while opening the file (even if done manually) -- it will just keep the opening file dialog open, with a full status bar, but will never actually proceed to opening the file or present an error. So, when we run the macro, it runs forever, trying to open the file but it is unable to proceed because the file never opens.

I am trying to add a timer to the function so that "if rawdata.xlsx takes longer than 5 minutes to open, cancel and stop procedure."

So far, I'm trying the following (file names have been changed for placeholders):

```
Sub wbprocess()

Dim Start, MaxTime, OpenStatus
OpenStatus = False
Start = Timer
MaxTime = 300 '(seconds)

Do While Timer < Start + MaxTime Or OpenStatus = False
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(input file here)
' calculations and rest of code here
wb.SaveAs Filename:=output file here, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
wb.Close
OpenStatus = True
Loop

End Sub
```

But, it won't leave the while loop until the max time has been reached, even if the file takes less than the allotted 5 minutes to open. What would be the correct logic to make it leave the while loop, and continue the calculations once the file has opened?

Comment: If your code gets stuck on the Workbooks.Open line, that's where it will stay, just as in your original code.  When the Open fails do you get any warning message, or it just hangs?

Comment: Right, and it just hangs on that line, never showing a warning, but also never completing the open.  Is it even possibly for the timer while loop to run concurrently and update while it's trying to open, since it's stuck on that single line?

Comment: I think I figured part of my issue...I should be using 'And' instead of 'Or' for the while loop conditions. That way if one of the conditions are met, the loop stops.  Before, it would keep running the loop until both OpenStatus=True and the timer had been exceeded, because only one of the conditions had to match to keep it running.

Comment: But next question, will the while loop continuously update itself while it is trying to open the file? As in, while the Workbooks.Open command is ongoing, does the timer update as well?

Comment: `Workbooks.Open()` is *synchronous*, so it will stay on that line until it's done opening the file, which is your case seems to be "forever"

Comment: @TimWilliams do you know of any work around for this that would implement some error message if it takes over a set amount of time to open? Thanks